# Copying pixel data directly from windows Device Context to an openGL rendering context

Tags: winapi, opengl, gdi

Is it possible to copy pixel data directly from a windows device context into an openGL rendering context (an openGL texture, to be specific)? I know that I can copy the windows device context pixel data into system memory (take it out of the graphics card), and then later upload it back into my openGL framebuffer, but what I'm looking for is a direct transfer where the data doesn't have to leave the GPU.

I am trying to write an application that is essentially a virtual magnifier. It consists of one window, which displays the contents of any other windows that are open underneath it. The target for my application is machines with windows 8 and higher, and I am using the basic win32 API. The reason why I want to use openGL to display the contents of my window is because I wish to perform various spatial transformations (distortions) with the GPU, not just magnification. Using openGL, I believe I can perform these transformations very fast.

Previously, I thought that all I had to do was to "move" my openGL rendering context onto each "third party" window that I wanted to steal pixel data from, and use glReadPixels() to copy this data into a PBO. I could then switch my rendering context back to my magnifier window, and proceed with rendering. However, I understand that this isn't possible, because openGL doesn't have access to any pixel data that wasn't rendered using openGL itself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization. Why not copy pixel data to system memory, and construct an OpenGL texture from it? If nothing else it will give you a feeling for the performance you can expect, and a baseline for potential future profiling comparisons.

Comment: I have indeed taken the route of first copying pixel data into system memory, and then copying it back into an openGL texture. It seems as though this approach is fast enough for my purposes.